# Template extraction of namespace node values from RSS using Feedme plugin

Tags: rss, plugin-feedme

I'm using the Feed Me plugin in a template to extract data from an RSS feed.

So if the RSS contains the following snippet

```
<category>Physiology</category>
<pubDate>Mon, 02 Nov 2015 00:00:00 +1100</pubDate>
<dc:creator>Joe Bloggs</dc:creator>
```

I can extract the data for the first two nodes using `{{ node.category }}` or `{{ node.pubDate }}`. But for the third `{{ node.creator }}` doesn't work and `{{ node.dc:creator }}` results in an error.

What is the correct way to extract node data that has a namespace defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [example](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe#template-example) actually shows, you'd reference these sort of nodes using the array notation.

```
{{ node['dc:creator'] }}
```

Comment: Indeed it does - I guess I didn't understand what that was even though it seems obvious now :) Thank you @crawf

Comment: No worries - its a little hidden away in the example :)